# Como passar dados de um input para outro com html e javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

Galera eu to com um problemão, ja pesquisei bastante e não consegui resolver o meu problema. Eu espero que vocês consigam me ajudar!

Eu tenho uma página (em html) com uma form. Gostaria que o valor colocado no input da primeira form, ao clicar em Submit, fosse colocado no valor do input da segunda form automaticamente.

Esse é o primeiro código, da primeira página. Tirei esse código de uma pergunta aqui no overflow das gringa.

```html
    <html>
<head>

<form action="display.html" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="serialNumber" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

A segunda página seria essa:

```html
    <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="write">
        <p>O valor é: </p>
    </div>
  
    
    <script>
// from display.html
document.getElementById("write").innerHTML = window.location.search; // you will have to parse
                                                                     // the query string to extract the
                                                                     // parameter you need
                  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ele funciona, mas o problema é que eu gostaria que o valor do primeir input fosse colocado dentro da mesma forma, na segunda página, só não consigo encaixar os códigos.

Para conseguir colocar o `id="write"` aqui dentro, pra acontecer o que eu estou tentando fazer.

```html
 <input type="text" name="serialNumber" />
```

Muito obrigado galera, eu sei que essa é uma comunidade muito bacana, mesmo sem me inscrever, eu ja achei resposta para todas as minhas dúvidas com vocês!

Comment: O que você já tentou e qual erro aconteceu?

Comment: Eu não achei nada específico pra resolver o que eu preciso, php pra mim é muito confuso ainda, não consegui fazer funcionar!

Comment: Já tentou usar `session`?

Comment: Gente, eu editei a pergunta, agora eu acho que vai ficar mais compreensível minha dúvida.

Comment: @GabrielMattoso dê mais detalhes, por favor. Você usa alguma linguagem server-side (php, nodejs, C#) para processar esses dados? Você quer fazer somente no lado do cliente (navegador, com javascript e html)?

Comment: Somente com JavaScript e Html, os dados vão ser processados na segunda form com um autoresponder, eu só quero passar o nome de uma form superficial para a outra do autoresponde, onde la a própria pessoa vai completar os dados e enviar.

Comment: Já que é uma requisição GET, o parâmetro estará na url. Na sua segunda página, extraia o valor do parâmetro na url, [esta pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/901115/4056678) pode ajudar.

Comment: vou dar uma olhada na pergunta Renan, valeu cara!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso você queria fazer isso em PHP é bem simples!

Ficaria assim:

- Pagina1.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Aqui você trocaria o nome do 'pagina2.php' para o nome da sua segunda pagina, porém ela precisa estar em .php, caso não esteja é so renomear! -->
 <form action="pagina2.php" method="post"> 
  <label for="nome"></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="nome aqui" name="nome" id="nome">
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

- Pagina2.php

```html
<?php 

$nome = $_POST['nome']; // Aqui estou pegando via POST da outra página e atribuindo o valor na variavel nome

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="pagina2.php" method="post">
  <label for="nome"></label>
  <!-- Dentro do value eu abri uma tag php para printar dentro do input o valor da variável nome -->
  <input type="text" placeholder="nome aqui" name="nome" id="nome" value="<?php echo $nome ?>">
  <label for="nome"></label>
  <input type="email" placeholder="email aqui" name="email" id="email">
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

É importante lembrar que o PHP é SERVER-SIDE, então você precisa de um servidor local ai para rodar!! Caso não manje disso, manda ai nos comentários que eu te dou uma força!

Comment: O AP não informou PHP na pergunta.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Ele editou a pergunta, mas tinha citado que tentou fazer em php, mas não conhecia muito. Vou deixar a resposta por alguns minutos, caso ele não se manifestar eu retiro!

Comment: Giovanni, se eu pegar esses dois códigos, criar os dois arquivos e colocar no servidor do meu site apenas pra testar, eles vão rodar?!

Comment: @GabrielMattoso Sim! Você só precisa salvar os arquivos com o mesmo nome.

Comment: Salvar os dois arquivos com o mesmo nome né?!

Comment: O primeiro como qualquer nome, tanto faz e o segundo como pagina2.php

Comment: Sim entendi, porque tem a chamada no código do primeiro né?! Mas Giovanni, funcionou perfeitamente, fiquei até impressionado com a simplicidade! Além de funcionar eu entendi o funcionamento do post, muito legal mesmo!

Comment: Gabriel, não esquece de marcar a resposta dele caso tenha resolvido se problema

Comment: @GabrielMattoso Exatamente! O PHP é bem bacana para pegar o gosto da coisa haha, mas continua estudando JS que ta muito em alta hoje em dia ;)

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda de vocês! Deus abençoe.

Comment: Como eu marco como resolvido? kkkkkk

Answer (score 1):

Você não citou qual é a linguagem server-side que você está usando para processar esses dados (ou talvez nem tenha  uma para citar). Então a solução que eu daria para isso seria usando `localStorage`.

Você salva o valor na página atual e, em seguida, captura na próxima.

```
#pagina_1.html

$('[type=serialNumber]').keyup(function () {
     localStorage.setItem('serialNumber', this.value);
});
```

Em seguida:

```
#pagina_2.html

var valor = localStorage.getItem('serialNumber')

$('#write > p').val('O valor é igual a :' + valor);
```

Comment: Parece fazer mais sentido do que eu estava fazendo, mas desculpe minha ignorância, como isso ficaria no código, estou muito confuso.

Comment: Olha, eu editei. Eu respondi acreditando que você tenha um conhecimento sobre Javascript ou jQuery. Pelo menos o que ficou claro para mim, eu pude ajudar. Se tem mais algum detalhe, edite sua pergunta, para que nós possamos dar mais detalhes.

Comment: Wallace, muito obrigado. Eu realmente sou muito leigo em Javascript e jQuery. Agora ficou um pouco mais fácil para compreender, vou dar uma olhada com calma e se conseguir eu te aviso, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Dá pra fazer isso usando apenas JavaScript e HTML:

**script.js**

```
function gohome(){
    window.location='form1.html';
}
function save(){
    window.localStorage.setItem('campo1', $('#campo1').val());
}
function load(){
    $('#campo2').val(window.localStorage.getItem('campo1'));
}
function erase(){
    window.localStorage.removeItem('campo1');
}
```

**form1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form1</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="save()" onunload="save()">
        <form name="form1" id="form1" action="form2.html" method="post">
            <input id="campo1" name="campo1" value="ValorCampo1"><br>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" id="form1-submit">Confirmar</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**form2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form2</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="load()" onunload="erase()">
        <form name="form2" id="form2" action="form1.html" method="get">
            <input id="campo2" name="campo2"><br>
            <br>
            <button type="button" id="form2-submit" onclick="gohome()">Confirmar</button>
        </form>        
    </body>
</html>
```